# What are the enzymes with the lowest concentrations in a cell?

Tags: enzymes, proteomics

Or are there any enzymes which are only translated one time per cell?

Comment: Please include your question in the body of the question. A title is not part of the question. You can't start a question with "or". You mention a cell. Clarify. Eukaryotic or porkaryotic. If eukaryotic, multicellular or unicellular? There are often low concentrations of enzymes in non-specialised cells, when these are hugely expressed in other differentiated cells. Really only enzymes or any proteins?